# Jboss Web (Running PHP script in jboss ) cannot find SAPI class error

Tags: java, php, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-web

I am facing a problem that i want to run php script inside jboss AS 7.1.1 for that :

i installed APR and AJP into the jboss

now its states that

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-
host].[/php-examples]] (MSC service thread 1-2) StandardWrapper.Throwable: java.
lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find SAPI class, no libphp5servlet in java.libr
ary.path(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\s
```

i downloaded jboss-native-2.0.10-windows-x86-ssl for my windows 32 bit system and did the proper installation for Jboss nativa API

then

i also installed php5servlet-windows-i586-SP1_2 this into C drive as PHP5 Folder and edit the php.ini file accordingly.

now it states that Can't find SAPI class..?

please help me what is this SAPI class ? is this compulsory ?

I am try this using php-examples.war file which comes with php5servlet-windows-i586-SP1_2 distribution